# How to make a surface with a transparent background in pygame

Tags: python, transparency, pygame

Can someone give me some example code that creates a surface with a transparent background in pygame?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This should do it:

```
image = pygame.Surface([640,480], pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
image = image.convert_alpha()
```

Make sure that the color depth (32) stays explicitly set else this will not work.

Comment: I second that - `image = pygame.Surface([640, 480], pygame.SRCALPHA)` is all you need.

Comment: I would like to also add that you now set colors like this: `cloud_color = (255, 255, 255, 120)` where the last value can range from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 25):

You can also give it a colorkey, much like GIF file transparency. This is the most common way to make sprites. The original bitmap has the artwork, and has a certain color as background that will not be drawn, which is the colorkey:

```
surf.set_colorkey((255,0,255)) // Sets the colorkey to that hideous purple
```

Surfaces that uses colorkey instead of alpha are a lot faster to blit since they don't require any blend math. The SDL surface uses a simple bitmask when it has a colorkey set, which blits practically without overhead.

Comment: This is the right answer. Link : https://riptutorial.com/pygame/example/23788/transparency

Answer (score 7):

You have 3 possibilities:

- Set a transparent color key with [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)

  The color key specifies the color that is treated as transparent. For example, if you have an image with a black background that should be transparent, set a black color key:

  ```py
  my_surface.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
  ```
- You can enable additional functions when creating a new surface. Set the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a surface with an image format that includes a per-pixel alpha.  The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 0):

  ```py
  my_surface = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
  ```
- Use [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) to create a copy of the *Surface* with an image format that provides alpha per pixel.

  However, if you create a new surface and use `convert_alpha()`, the alpha channels are initially set to maximum.  The initial value of the pixels is (0, 0, 0, 255). You need to fill the entire surface with a transparent color before you can draw anything on it:

  ```py
  my_surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
  my_surface = my_surface.convert_alpha()
  my_surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
  ```