# How can I fill my pygame.Surface() with a custom image instead of a plain block?

Tags: python, pygame

I have this code:

```py
import pygame

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, groups):
    super().__init__(groups)
    self.loaded_image = pygame.image.load('Folder/MyImage.png')  # I added an image and I want to
    self.image = pygame.Surface((64, 64))  # <------------------------ add it here
```

In simple words, I have a `pygame.Surface` and I want to change the `pygame.Surface`'s value to my `self.loaded_image`. Is it possible? Because usually `pygame.Surface` just displays a plain block and you can fill it with only plain colors, but instead of a plain block, I want it to be a custom image. How?

Comment: You can use the `blit` function to paste a surface on top of another

Comment: The image itself is already a surface. You don't need to put it inside another surface to blit it. If you want to rescale your image, use `pygame.transform.scale`.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that if the image isn't completely solid and has a transparent background, you'll need to create a surface with an alpha channel (see [How to make a surface with a transparent background in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328061/how-to-make-a-surface-with-a-transparent-background-in-pygame/64512639#64512639)):

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface((64, 64), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

---

If the images are the same size, simply `blit` the image

```py
self.image.blit(self.loaded_image, (0, 0))
```

If the images are different sizes, use `pygame.transform.smoothscale`

```py
pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.loaded_image,
    self.image.get_size(), dest_surface=self.image)
```

or `pygame.transform.scale`

```py
pygame.transform.scale(self.loaded_image, 
    self.image.get_size(), dest_surface=self.image)
```