# Sprite shadow changing to full black

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

[player.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTI7e.png)
[shadow comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reeZH.jpg)

The shadows are different when I blit the player image to a surface and then loading that surface to the display vs loading the entire image on the display

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 736))
display.fill('#555358')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_1 = pygame.Surface((16, 16)).convert_alpha()
    image_1.blit(
        pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha(),
        (0, 0),
        (16, 32, 16, 16))
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image_1, (16 * 3, 16 * 3))
    image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    display.blit(image, (0, 96))

    image_2 = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha()
    image_2 = pygame.transform.scale(image_2, (288 * 3, 240 * 3))
    display.blit(image_2, (0, 0))

    while True:
        # Process player inputs.
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                raise SystemExit

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

I thought setting the color key was messing with it, so I tried removing it to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a surface with an alpha channel (`pygame.SRCALPHA`) instead of converting it with `convert_alpha` and setting a color key with `set_colorkey`:

```py
image_1 = pygame.Surface((16, 16), pygame.SRCALPHA)
image_1.blit(
        pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha(),
        (0, 0),
        (16, 32, 16, 16))
image = pygame.transform.scale(image_1, (16 * 3, 16 * 3))
display.blit(image, (0, 96))
```

Note: `pygame.Surface((16, 16))` creates a completely black surface. In contrast, `pygame.Surface((16, 16), pygame.SRCALPHA)` creates a completely transparent surface. `convert_alpha()` changes the format of the image, but it remains solid black. Also see [How to make a surface with a transparent background in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328061/how-to-make-a-surface-with-a-transparent-background-in-pygame/64512639#64512639).

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't expect a response this fast. I was following a tutorial except for the assets he was using so I didn't know much on how to solve the problem, thanks again!